# How to add lines to end of file on Linux

Tags: linux, shell

I want to add the following 2 lines:

```sh
VNCSERVERS="1:root"
VNCSERVERARGS[1]="-geometry 1600x1200"
```

to the end of the file `vncservers` found at the directory `/etc/sysconfig/`.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can use `vi` or `emacs`. Do you know how to use those? I am not trying to be sarcastic.

Answer (score 269, accepted):

The easiest way is to redirect the output of the `echo` by `>>`:

```sh
echo 'VNCSERVERS="1:root"' >> /etc/sysconfig/configfile
echo 'VNCSERVERARGS[1]="-geometry 1600x1200"' >> /etc/sysconfig/configfile
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how would you append text to a file without creating a new line?

Comment: It depends on the last added line, not your current command.
When you do the 
$ echo "foobar" >> file,the newline is already there. If you do $ echo -n "foobar" >> file, you won't append the newline to the end of the line, so you'll write in the same line.

Comment: So the echo command is responsible for the new line. I would never have figured that out. Thank you, very useful.

Comment: This does not work when in a sudo environment writing to a system file. You cannot sudo >>. Otherwise, it works fine.

Comment: Use can you "sed" command as follow:
----------
sed -i "$ a some text" somefile.txt
 ---------
-i: edit files in place,
$ find end of file,
a: append

Comment: @Dennis That's because of the way the command line is parsed. 'sudo abc >> def' will 'sudo abc' and then '>> def' the output. In order to sudo the entire 'abc >> def' bit, you must do something like this:
sudo sh -c "echo 'VNCSERVERS=\"1:root\"' >> /etc/sysconfig/configfile" (note that the inner double-quotes must be escaped)

Comment: I have a use case in circle ci where this add to last line, not on next line. I need something more reliable. I tried tee and it also fail. I tried to create a reproduction and it does work fine so I can't ask my question. It's a dot env file with secret. Any clue ?

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa Yes, your file does not have a newline character at the end, that's why when you add a new line to the end of the file it gets appended to the last line of the file instead of being a line of its own. See the output of `printf %s 1 > tmp && echo 2 >> tmp && cat tmp`.